# How can I find the same element in different pages of web-site by using RobotFramework?

Tags: robotframework

I'm testing one Internet Shop. There are a lot of pages with articles and descriptions for them. I have to find all of articles with a void descriptions. How to make it for a single page is clear. How to finde the same element in difwrent pages?

here ist testCase for a single article page:

```
[Setup]    Log To Console    TestCase Beschreibung gestartet
Open Browser    ${url_test}    ${BROWSER}
Page Should Contain Element   xpath=/html/body/div[4]/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]      
Element Should Be Visible    xpath=/html/body/div[4]/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]      
Close Browser
[Teardown]    Log To Console    TestCase Beschreibung beendet
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of pages, and the locator is always the same, you can use `Go To    ${url}` in a FOR loop and have run your verification (after making it a keyword).

[EDIT] If the new page is opened from the action of an element, then you can use [Switch Window](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Switch%20Window).

Note: Your locator is using absolute path, and the root /html/body can be simplified by //. Also it would be better to use some element unique identifier, like "name" or "id".

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I do not have a list of pages. In order to go to another page I write like "press the "next" button." But the locator on all pages is the same.

Comment: You mentioned a "lot of pages", so I assume it is not a single page site. See if my edit helps.